Devise Layout for Login
I create custom layout for admin and not using applicaiton.html.erb, I am using new layout admin.html.erb ,and I can import in any controller, and its working fine, but I need to use this for devise login page (session ). I tried alot of ways but no luck so far. If I add this line in application_contrller.rb, its working fine (layout 'home'), but I don't need for all of my application only for admin side login page.
I tried this as well in application.rb, but no luck.
config.to_prepare do
    Devise::SessionsController.layout "admin"
   
end


I was able to do it by running this command first rails generate devise:controllers admin_users
and then added layout like this
class AdminUsers::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'admin'
end

and its working.
